# What is the Java equivalent of creating an anonymous object in C#?

Tags: c#, java

In C#, you can do the following:

`var objResult = new { success = result };`

Is there a java equivalent for this?

Comment: what is `success`, and what is `result`?

Comment: success would be the name of the field, result an arbitrary object, resolved to the current type of the result variable. If it were 
`int result = 3;`
`var obj = new { success = result };`
    obj would be a class with one field: int success

Comment: Correct. In my case, `success` is a `Boolean` and `result` was `true` or `false`.

Comment: `success` wouldn't be a field, but a readonly property in C#.

Comment: Working in Java again 11 years later...imagine my surprise when I googled this and it was the first result.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Java does not have type inference provided to C# by the `var` keyword, so whilst you can create anonymous types they're not much good since you can't get at their attributes.

So you can create an instance of an anonymous class like so:

```
Object myobj = new Object() {
  public final boolean success = true;
}
```

But since `myobj` is an instance of `Object` you can't access `success` in your code, and as you have created an instance of an *anonymous* class there is by definition no way to explicitly refer to this class.

In C# `var` solves this by inferring the type but there is no way to do this in Java.

Normally anonymous classes are used to create implementations of interfaces and abstract classes and so are referenced using the interface or parent class as the type.

Comment: To read this, it is absolutely insane that you need to create a class file for just a simple class/type with some properties to extend readability. Yikes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really pleased being moved from .Net projects to java.. This is nuts

Comment: @Codebeat You can declare an inner class, or even a local class right before declaring the variable, to avoid creating a whole class file. Still clunky maybe, but not as insane.

Answer (score 25):

With Java 10 you can use anonymous classes:

```
boolean result = true;

var objResult = new Object() {
    boolean success = result;
};

System.out.println(objResult.success);
```

You can use them with streams:

```
var names = List.of("John", "Peter", "Olaf");

var namesAndLength = names.stream().map(n -> new Object() {
    String name = n;
    int length = n.length();
}).collect(toList());
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference

Comment: Java is always a few years behind C#.   Now if only Java had operator overloading.

Comment: I think this is slightly more verbose (extra Object() and field types) but more powerful than C# since you can also define methods here. Just for passing data probably record can be considered.

Answer (score 11):

You can definitely write the equivalent as

```
Object objResult = new Object() {
    boolean success = result;
}
```

What you've done in this case is create an inline anonymous subclass of `Object`, which contains a `success` field instantiated to the value of `result` (which I've assumed is a boolean here, but could be anything).

However, this isn't very useful - since Java is strongly typed, and you have no way to refer to the anonymous class you created, you won't be able to refer to the `success` variable anywhere.  Anonymous subclasses are generally used to either implement single-method interfaces, or perhaps provide an override of a superclass method - both of these cases are more useful since other code can invoke the overridden behaviour via the method declared on the parent class/interface.

So an anonymous subclass of Object which *might* be useful could be something like the following:

```
Object objresult = new Object() {
    @Override public String toString() {
        return result.toString(); 
    }
}
```

This behaviour is now exposed as you can call `objResult.toString()` in order to get the stringified result out.

In practice it would be better to define an interface with a `getResult()` method instead, and then implement this with either a concrete or anonymous class.

Comment: Yeah, I found that out the hard way. Not sure what good that would be though, as you said. - Just saw your edit.

Answer (score 10):

You just have a harder time getting the information out again:

```
Object objResult = new Object(){ public final boolean success = result; };
```

To get the fields you have to use reflection:

```
objResult.getClass().getDeclaredField("success").getBoolean(objResult)
```

For different types of the field `success` you will need different getters for the value.

Comment: The anonymous class created has package visibility. How do you do this in a package that is not the one you created this anonymous class?

Answer (score 2):

There is similar but not identical functionality in the form of anonymous classes. The difference being that they have to implement a particular named interface or extend a named class.

```
SomeInterface obj = new SomeInterface() {
    // implement the interface
}
```

So, to approximate your example:

```
interface Result
{
    bool getSuccess();
}

// ...

bool result = DoSomething();
Result objResult = new Result() {
    bool getSuccess() { return result; }
}
```

But there is not much gain for this example.

http://www.docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm

Comment: They're not really similar features, other than the name.

Comment: Well the class is anonymous. The interface isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Java has no equivalent feature for implicitly defining types with implemented by returning values. I guess the closest equivalent code would be to define an interface of "get" methods together with a handmade implementation.

```
interface Result {
    boolean success();
}
Result objResult = new Result() {
    public boolean success() { return result; }
};
```

You are probably better off taking a more Java-like approach to the specific problem. C# anonymous objects and Java anonymous classes are similar in name, but not functionality.