# how to send an anonymous object as a method param?

Tags: java, android, object

I want to call this method:

```
Foo(Object obj);
```

I tried to call it like this:

```
Foo(new Object(){
            latitude ="32.4578",
            longitude ="34.4578",
            index ="0",
            size ="10" });
```

but got an error.

how should I create and send an anonymous object>

Comment: What should this be? This is not Java. You can't add your own variables to an `Object`. You have to create a new class.

Comment: i know this from .net. so there is no way to create dynamic anonymous class? I have to declare a new names class every time?

Comment: No this should be fine, but change your commas for `;` within the class body and declare the variable type. What error do you get?

Comment: You are right. Didn't know this. But however: The method `Foo()` expects an `Object` and an `Object` does not have those members. Thus you could not access them. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488833/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-creating-an-anonymous-object-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so there is no way to create dynamic anonymous class?

Yes, but they will not look like what you have there.

This syntax will compile:

```
Object o=new Object() {
      String latitude="32.4578";
      String longitude="34.4578";
      String index="0";
      String size="10";
    };
```

However, it will be useless, as nothing can access those values.

In Java, anonymous inner classes are primarily for defining *behavior*, in the form of overriding methods of some superclass or interface. They might also have data, in the form of data members, but that data will only be visible to the extent that the anonymous inner class uses that data from those overridden methods.

Comment: Well, he could access it via reflection.  I believe anyone who maintains that code afterwards has the right to shoot him though.

Comment: @GabeSechan: Yes, I think that coding approach would violate the Geneva Conventions or something. :)

Comment: all i want is to serialize it to json. so it will be enough