# Return anonymous object in java

Tags: java, javascript

In JavaScript we can do:

```
function foo() {
   ...

    return {
        attr1 : ... ,
        attr2 : ...,
       };
}
```

But what is its equivalent in Java?

Because I want to return a custom Json object from my controller after an ajax call and I want to create a new bean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Java equivalent of creating an anonymous object in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488833/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-creating-an-anonymous-object-in-c)

Comment: You have to define a new class, there are no anonymous objects in Java

Comment: You can't really compare the two languages like that

Comment: I would use a `Map` instead.

Comment: As last resort, you can always return an `Object`, but then you cannot return a primitive

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza but i have different type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Java dictates, you should create a new class and convert it to JSON. Also, you can use `Map<String,Object>` to accomplish the same thing. To generate following JSON:

```
{
    "attr1":1,
    "attr2":2
}
```

you can use following code:

```
 Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>(3);
 map.put("attr1", 1);
 map.put("attr2", 2);
```

and convert it to JSON.

P.S.: `HashMap` in Java causes your heap to increase and unnecessary garbage, so I specified just enough size to keep two elements.

Comment: Why not just `new HashMap<>(2);` ?

Comment: There is factor issue, which is 0.75 default. It means, when 75% of the `HashMap` is full, it's expanded to a larger size and it takes time when your map is large. You can specify factor value in constructor.