# Java8+: Pass Anonymous Object to Method

Tags: java, object

How can I pass an anonymous Object to a method (in an other class) and read the data like in the non-working example below?

```
    public static void caller() {
        Object obj = new Object() { final String name = "Aloha from Hawaii"; };
        consumer(obj);
    }

    public static void consumer(Object obj) {
        System.out.println(obj.name);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a link to any tutorial that mentions "*Anonymous **Object***".

Comment: This question has your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488833/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-creating-an-anonymous-object-in-c

Comment: @PM77-1 : https://www.javatpoint.com/object-and-class-in-java#objectannonymous

Comment: Terrible terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to the link provided by jdabtieu:

```
    public static void consumer(Object obj) {
        try {
            System.out.println(obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("name").get(obj));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException ignored) {
        }
    }
```

Is it really that complicated?
However, it's working - and if there is no better solution I'll stay with it.

Many thanks